# parseFloat keeps returning NaN when it should be -0.1 or 0.1

Tags: javascript

parseFloat keeps returning NaN when it should be -0.1 or 0.1 when I print it in console.log, I'm most-likely just getting tired, but I can't see the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated as always,
Also not looking for a jQuery answer here, this must be JS

```
function startUp() {
    var fontButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("fontsizer");
    for (var i=0; i < fontButtons.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("fontsizer")[i].addEventListener("click", resizeText);
    }
};

window.onload = startUp;

function resizeText() {
    var fontChange = parseFloat(this.value);
    console.log(fontChange);
    if (document.body.style = "") {
        document.body.setAttribute("style", "font-size:1.0em;");
    }
    var currentFontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize.replace('em', ''));
    console.log(currentFontSize);
    document.body.style.fontSize = (currentFontSize + fontChange) + "em";
};
```

and the html

```
<div id="fontbuttons">
 <input class="fontsizer" value="-0.1" type="image" id="fontdown" alt="-" src="fontdown.png" />
 <input class="fontsizer" value="0.1" type="image" id="fontup" alt="+" src="fontup.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems.

**First**, setting the attribute to `onclick` and passing in the callback as a string will use `eval` to invoke the function and `this` will point to the global object, so use `addEventListener('click', resizeText)` instead.

---

**Second**, you can't `parseFloat` on a number with letters like that - strip out the `em` before parsing:

```
var currentFontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize.replace('em', ''));
```

---

**Third**, you're concatenating instead of adding. Change

```
document.body.style.fontSize = currentFontSize + fontChange + "em"
```

to

```
document.body.style.fontSize = (currentFontSize + fontChange) + "em"
```

---

Working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/8tv550us/

Comment: Ok, so everything works except the second part, its still returning NaN, I updated the code in the original post, any thought?

Comment: I feel some something isn't correct in my if statment

Answer (score 1):

I believe this.value within your resizeText() function is where your error lies.  what do you think 'this' is referring to here? I think it will be the window object at the moment.

Comment: You are correct, but explain why and how to fix it.

Comment: ah, thank you, it should be the value of the button clicked. Too much code today haha thank you

Comment: Any thought on why the second parse is returning NaN? I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener rather than setting an attribute and `this` will point to the correct object

```
document.getElementsByClassName("fontsizer")[i].addEventListener("click", resizeText);
```